# Disable hover tooltip but enable "editor.hover.sticky" using keybinding for Color Picker Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, tooltip

I disabled the hover tooltip by placing `"editor.hover.enabled": false,` in the settings.json file (the automatic pop up is not ideal). However, when I use a set keybinding to view, say, the Color Picker, it appears and then disappears on mouse over or when the mouse moves.

Tried to also set `"editor.hover.sticky": true,` expecting to be able to mouse over the Color Picker, but the same occurs.

Comment: please show the JSON for the keybinding you created to show the hover. When I make a keybinding that uses the `editor.action.showHover` command, it works just fine.

Comment: @user I found a work around that involves holding down the keybinding command while moving mouse over the Color Picker. I double checked the editor.action.showHover command and tried to reset it. Mouse over still makes the Color Picker disappear unless I hold down the command. Thank you.